# How to query count() with different grouping from same table?

Tags: sql, count

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE COST1 (
    REGION,
    IS_SERVICED,
)
```

`IS_SERVICED` is either true or false. Region is not unique. I would like to return a data set with 3 columns; REGION, COUNT_TRUE, COUNT_FALSE. How do I write a single query to produce the count of both true & false, grouped by region, if I need to place the where/having conditional to identify one of them.
I can do this with multiple CTEs as follows:

```
WITH TRUE_COUNT_TABLE (REGION, TRUE_COUNT) AS
(SELECT REGION, count(*) FROM TABLE1
WHERE IS_SERVICED like 'TRUE'
GROUP BY REGION),
FALSE_COUNT_TABLE (REGION, FALSE_COUNT) AS
(SELECT REGION, count(*) FROM TABLE1
WHERE IS_SERVICED like 'FALSE'
GROUP BY REGION)

SELECT REGION, TRUE_COUNT, FALSE_COUNT FROM TRUE_TABLE t JOIN FALSE_TABLE f
ON t.REGION = f.REGION;
```

Is there a way to do this in a single query? (Also, did I use `WHERE` correctly, or should `HAVING` have been used here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `SUM` with a condition

```
SELECT 
  REGION
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN IS_SERVICED = 'TRUE' then 1 else 0 END) as TRUE_COUNT
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN IS_SERVICED = 'FALSE' then 1 else 0 END) as FALSE_COUNT 
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY REGION
```